# Making CSS X{text-transforlm:capitalize} to selectively leave some words uncapitalized

Tags: html, css

This property transforms the first letter of each word in the element capitalized. A common practice for bloggers is to use headers, like "My First Article", but usually not all the beginning letters are capitalized, for example "This is the First Article on My Blog".
How can I make CSS to transform the first letters of all words in specific elements (e.g. h1, h2), but leave some specific words uncapitalized (e.g. "a", "the", "is", "of")?

Comment: Wrap the letters you want capitalised in a span with a class, and apply `text-transform` to the class.

Comment: Or you can just type the words out like they should be, to me that's the proper solution to this. It's only for titles, shouldn't cause too much hassle

Comment: @Huangism yup, I should have thought of that!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the  tag to this uncapitalized words, like this:

```
<style>
p {text-transform:capitalize}
p span {text-transform:none}
</style>
<p>This <span>is the</span> First Article <span>on</span> My Blog<p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap the specific words inside a span tag, you can override the case.

Css:

```
.text {
 text-transform: capitalize;
}
.text span {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

Html :

```
<div class="text">All capitalize but <span>specific words</span> is lowercase</div>
```